# htaccess force www not for cdn

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with `.htaccess` forcing www.

I have the main site http://www.portalesardegna.com and I want to redirect http://portalesardegna.com to the www version, but I have even a CDN, http://cdn.portalesardegna.com, if I look the site with pingdom http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/eHy16D/www.portalesardegna.com all the files in the cdn are redirected to the www version.

Some information that can be useful:

1. The CDN is on an external service, and the dns point to another server, not mine.
2. I have some images from another subdomain in my site, private3.portalesardegna.com, and all of these images are not redirected.

Here is the code i use in the htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cdn\..+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you set up cdn. with a different virtual host? This will save you all kinds of trouble.

Comment: My cdn.portalesardegna.com subdomain point to the CDN ip is not hosted in my server, can this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule as as your very first rule in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(cdn|www)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Definitely not due to to this rule. You have some rule outside this .htaccess doing that.